# LNI/alpha change abbreviation of multiple citations

Tags: biblatex

Is it possible to change the semicolon in LNI alpha style if multiple publications are referenced? Instead of [AB01;AB02] to [AB01,AB02].

I am using `biblatex`, and `biber`, together with the LNI style.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone intereseted, add this line after your biblatex package:

```
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}
```